# EclipseLink ADD CONSTRAINT Exception

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, eclipselink

I would like to use create-or-extend-tables but eclipselink gives below error after tables were created. I am using Eclipselink 2.5.2 and db is MS Sql 2014

> Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
>   'announcementCOMPANY_ID' object already exists. Error Code: 2714 Call:
>   ALTER TABLE announcement ADD CONSTRAINT announcementCOMPANY_ID FOREIGN
>   KEY (COMPANY_ID) REFERENCES company (ID) Query:
>   DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE announcement ADD CONSTRAINT
>   announcementCOMPANY_ID FOREIGN KEY (COMPANY_ID) REFERENCES company
>   (ID)")

**Persistance.java**

```
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", ConfigParams
                       .getInstance().getValue(ConfigConstants.JDBC_DRIVER));
         persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", ConfigParams
                       .getInstance().getValue(ConfigConstants.JDBC_USER));
         persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", ConfigParams
                       .getInstance().getValue(ConfigConstants.JDBC_PASSWORD));
         persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", ConfigParams
                       .getInstance().getValue(ConfigConstants.JDBC_URL));

         persistenceMap.put("eclipselink.logging.logger",
                       Log4jSessionLog.class.getName());
         // persistenceMap.put("eclipselink.logging.file",
         // Log4jSessionLog.class.getName());

         persistenceMap
                       .put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
         persistenceMap.put("eclipselink.weaving.internal", "false");
         persistenceMap.put("eclipselink.logging.level", ConfigParams
                       .getInstance().getValue(ConfigConstants.JDBC_LOGGING_LEVEL));
         persistenceMap.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation",
                       "create-or-extend-tables");
```

**Announcement.java**

@Entity
@Table(name="announcement")
public class Announcement {

```
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "annId")
        private int id;

        @Column(nullable =false, length = 250, name="annName")
        private String name;

        @Column(length = 250)
        private String mainTitle;

        @Column(nullable=false, length = 250)
        private String subTitle;

        @Lob
        private String content;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private Date startDate;

        @Transient
        private java.util.Date startDateUtil;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private Date endDate;

        @Transient
        private java.util.Date endDateUtil;

        @Lob
        private String imgUrl;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private boolean isActive;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private boolean isDeleted;

        @Transient
        private BtcResponse status;


        private Type type;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name="announcementLogs")
        private List<Log> logAList = new ArrayList<Log>();


        private Company company;

        public int getId() {
                    return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
                    this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
                    return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
        }

        public String getMainTitle() {
                    return mainTitle;
        }

        public void setMainTitle(String mainTitle) {
                    this.mainTitle = mainTitle;
        }

        public String getSubTitle() {
                    return subTitle;
        }

        public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
                    this.subTitle = subTitle;
        }

        public String getContent() {
                    return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
                    this.content = content;
        }

        public Date getStartDate() {
                    return startDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
                    this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        public java.util.Date getStartDateUtil() {
                    return startDateUtil;
        }

        public void setStartDateUtil(java.util.Date startDateUtil) {
                    this.startDateUtil = startDateUtil;
        }

        public Date getEndDate() {
                    return endDate;
        }

        public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
                    this.endDate = endDate;
        }

        public java.util.Date getEndDateUtil() {
                    return endDateUtil;
        }

        public void setEndDateUtil(java.util.Date endDateUtil) {
                    this.endDateUtil = endDateUtil;
        }

        public String getImgUrl() {
                    return imgUrl;
        }

        public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
                    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
                    return isActive;
        }

        public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
                    this.isActive = isActive;
        }

        public boolean isDeleted() {
                    return isDeleted;
        }

        public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
                    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        }

        public BtcResponse getStatus() {
                    return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(BtcResponse status) {
                    this.status = status;
        }

        public List<Log> getLogAList() {
                    return logAList;
        }

        public void setLogAList(List<Log> logAList) {
                    this.logAList = logAList;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        public Type getType() {
                    return type;
        }

        public void setType(Type type) {
                    this.type = type;
        }

        public Announcement() {
                    super();
        }

        public Announcement(BtcResponse status) {
                    super();
                    this.status = status;
        }

        public Announcement(java.util.Date startDateUtil,
                               java.util.Date endDateUtil, String imgUrl, boolean isActive) {
                    super();
                    this.startDateUtil = startDateUtil;
                    this.endDateUtil = endDateUtil;
                    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
                    this.isActive = isActive;
        }

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        public Company getCompany() {
                    return company;
        }
        public void setCompany(Company company) {
                    this.company = company;
        }
```

}

**Company.java**

@Entity
@Table(name="company")
public class Company {

```
        @Id      
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private int id;

        @Column(length = 100, nullable = false, name="companyName")
        private String name;


        private List<Banner> bannerList = new ArrayList<Banner>();


        private List<Announcement> announcementList = new ArrayList<Announcement>();


        private List<PriceList> priceList = new ArrayList<PriceList>();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
        public List<Announcement> getAnnouncementList() {
                    return announcementList;
        }

        public void setAnnouncementList(List<Announcement> announcementList) {
                    this.announcementList = announcementList;
        }

        @Transient
        private BtcResponse status;

        public int getId() {
                    return id;
        }

        public Company(int id, String name) {
                    super();
                    this.id = id;
                    this.name = name;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
                    this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
                    return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
        public List<Banner> getBannerList() {
                    return bannerList;
        }

        public void setBannerList(List<Banner> bannerList) {
                    this.bannerList = bannerList;
        }

        public BtcResponse getStatus() {
                    return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(BtcResponse status) {
                    this.status = status;
        }

        public Company() {
                    super();
        }

        public Company(BtcResponse status) {
                    super();
                    this.status = status;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
        public List<PriceList> getPriceList() {
                    return priceList;
        }

        public void setPriceList(List<PriceList> priceList) {
                    this.priceList = priceList;
        }
```

}

Comment: EclipseLink doesn't check if constraints already exist and just attempts to re-add them.  It logs all errors rather then just ignore them so that if the constraint wasn't created for some other reason, you can go back and check out why.  If the constraint is there, the errors for it can be ignored.

Comment: Dear @Chris ,
Thank you for your reply. there are 3 join tables and if i ignore them there will be 50-100mb log file.
Interesting thing is that;
if i set "eclipselink.ddl-generation" as  "create-or-extend-tables" than i get above error, if i set "create-tables" there is no error

Comment: If the table already exists, it doesn't create anything related to the table.  create-or-extend-tables is a development tool, and you should be able to change the log levels to filter out these messages if you need.  Feel free to file a bug/enhancement to make EclipseLink ignore these warnings, but as stated, they can be handy if your run into issues with the app and need to check out what might have gone wrong with DDL.